# Javascript function subtract from div not working.

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to subtract 50px from a div with a javascript function when it is called. Why isnt this working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
        function resizeDiv(id)
        {
            obj.style.height = ( parseFloat( obj.style.height ) - 50 ) + 'px';
        }
        </script>

<style type="text/css">
            #divId{
            background:blue;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="resizeDiv('divId')">Try it</button>   
    <div id="divId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define obj or a style property for height, and missed a bracket in the css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function resizeDiv(id){
   var obj=document.getElementById(id);
    if(obj){
        obj.style.height= (obj.offsetHeight- 50)+ 'px';
    }
}
</script>
<style type= "text/css">
#divId{
    background:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="resizeDiv('divId')">Try it</button>   
    <div id="divId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```